# How to create column aliases in a resource

Tags: laravel, resources, laravel-resource

I am creating an API using Laravel.

I created a table called `transaction`. I also created a resource called `transactionresource`.

I want to change the `id` column to be the `key` column in the API, and I don't want id to show in the API; instead key should show.

My code

```
class TransactionResource extends JsonResource
{
  
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $array = parent::toArray($request);

        // set the new key with data
        $array['key'] = $array['id'];

        // unset the old key
        unset($array['id']);
        
        return $array;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
{"success":false,"message":"Undefined array key \"id\""}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can return array of custom fields like this**

```
public function toArray($request){
   return [
    'key' => $this->id,
    ...
];}
```

[see documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#concept-overview)